# Why is sort by always using single reducer?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to execute the following query and it is taking forever to load data as only a single reducer is used for the second job.

INSERT INTO TABLE ddb_table
SELECT * FROM data_dump sort by rank desc LIMIT 1000000;

Two jobs are created for the above query. First job run pretty fast as it is using 80 mappers and about 22 reducers. Second job mappers are fast but it is super slow due to a single reducer.

I tried to increase reducer count with **set mapred.reduce.tasks=35** but interestingly it was applied only for the first job and not the second.

Why is a single reducer used? Is it because of the sort by clause?
How can I set max reducers?

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not positive, but my intuition is that it's because of the "limit", not the "sort by". In fact, "sort by" explicitly will only sort within each reducer, so you will not get a total ordering.

The issue is that if there are multiple reducers, they aren't coordinated enough to be able to know when they've reached 1000000 records. So to do limit, it must be only one reducer, which maintains a count of the number of records, and stops outputting new ones once the limit is reached.

In fact, even if it were possible to do "sort by" and "limit" with multiple reducers, you could get different output on different runs, depending on which reducer runs fastest, so I don't think what you're trying to do here makes sense in the first place.

Comment: Well I started with order by but since order by uses a single reducer I changed it to order by clause. What I am trying to do is really select the top million records after sorting by rank column.

Answer (score 2):

It is just the way sorting with default Partitioner works in Hadoop. Default partitioning uses hashcode mod number of reducers, so if you want 35 reducers, than you will get 35 output files, each sorted, but with overlapping ranges. For example you have keys starting with alpha characters [a..z]: file1 (a1,a2,a15,d3,d5,f6), file2(a3,a5,b1,z3), etc. 
In order to avoid the overlapping key ranges you either need one Reducer or you need to make your partitioner more aware of the nature of the keys, for example make you partitioner to direct all of the keys with the same first character into the same partition, thus there will be multiple files in the output, but none of the ranges will overlap. Ex file1 (a1,a2,a3,a5,a15), file2(b1),file3(....) file4(d3,d6), etc.
It works for when me I use standard Hadoop jobs or Apache PIG. Unfortunately I do not have Hive expirience, but you could try to use Dynamic Partitioning on the table you are inserting into.

Comment: Hive "sort by" does per-reducer sorting, so it is expected behavior that you would get multiple files like your first example: file1 (a1,a2,a15,d3,d5,f6), file2(a3,a5,b1,z3).

Hive "order by" does a total ordering and uses only one reducer.